# Having Problems to perform formulas in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I got this macro from this site but after running it the seems to behaving abnormally. Macro is running good and removing all blanks and empty rows and column but after running it I'm having problem to perform other formulas like plus minus in a range.

**My code**:

```
Sub RemoveBlankRowsColumns()

'PURPOSE: Remove blank rows or columns contained in the spreadsheets  UsedRange

Dim rng As Range
Dim rngDelete As Range
Dim RowCount As Long, ColCount As Long
Dim EmptyTest As Boolean, StopAtData As Boolean
Dim RowDeleteCount As Long, ColDeleteCount As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim UserAnswer As Variant

'Analyze the UsedRange
Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
rng.Select

RowCount = rng.Rows.Count
ColCount = rng.Columns.Count
DeleteCount = 0

'Optimize Code
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Loop Through Rows & Accumulate Rows to Delete
For x = RowCount To 1 Step -1
'Is Row Not Empty?
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng.Rows(x)) <> 0 Then
        If StopAtData = True Then Exit For
    Else
        If rngDelete Is Nothing Then Set rngDelete = rng.Rows(x)

        Set rngDelete = Union(rngDelete, rng.Rows(x))
        RowDeleteCount = RowDeleteCount + 1
    End If
Next x

'Delete Rows (if necessary)
If Not rngDelete Is Nothing Then
    rngDelete.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Set rngDelete = Nothing
End If

'Loop Through Columns & Accumulate Columns to Delete
For x = ColCount To 1 Step -1
    'Is Column Not Empty?
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng.Columns(x)) <> 0 Then
        If StopAtData = True Then Exit For
    Else
        If rngDelete Is Nothing Then Set rngDelete = rng.Columns(x)

        Set rngDelete = Union(rngDelete, rng.Columns(x))
        ColDeleteCount = ColDeleteCount + 1
    End If
Next x

'Delete Columns (if necessary)
If Not rngDelete Is Nothing Then
    rngDelete.Select
    rngDelete.EntireColumn.Delete
End If

'Refresh UsedRange (if necessary)
If RowDeleteCount + ColDeleteCount > 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: you should add more details about your issue: _"problem to perform other formulas like plus minus in a range."_

Comment: When people tell me they can't use formuas, usually what is happening is they somehow changed calculation to manual, and your sub actually has a line that does that. Try adding `Application.Calculation = xCalculationAutomatic` just before the `End Sub` line and see if it works.

Comment: From what I can see, you aren't re-enabling screenupdating and events. You should also add an error handler to the code that takes you to the end of the sub and enables these after so you won't have issues with updating and events not happening

Comment: Thanx both of you

Answer (score 0):

Condensed code:

```
Sub RemoveBlankRowsColumns()

    'PURPOSE: Remove blank rows or columns contained in the spreadsheets UsedRange

    Dim RowCount As Long, ColCount As Long, x As Long
    'Dim EmptyTest As Boolean, StopAtData As Boolean
    Dim RowDeleteCount As Long: RowDeleteCount = 0
    Dim ColDeleteCount As Long: ColDeleteCount = 0
    Dim DeleteCount As Long: DeleteCount = 0
    'Dim UserAnswer As Variant

    On Error GoTo ExitSub

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        RowCount = .Rows.Count
        ColCount = .Columns.Count

        'Optimize Code
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        'Loop Through Rows & Delete
        For x = RowCount To 1 Step -1
            'Is Row Not Empty?
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(x)) <> 0 Then
                If StopAtData = True Then Exit For
            Else
                .Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                RowDeleteCount = RowDeleteCount + 1
            End If
        Next x

        'Loop Through Columns & Delete
        For x = ColCount To 1 Step -1
            'Is Column Not Empty?
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(x)) <> 0 Then
                If StopAtData = True Then Exit For
            Else
                .Columns(x).EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlLeft
                ColDeleteCount = ColDeleteCount + 1
            End If
        Next x

        DeleteCount = RowDeleteCount + ColDeleteCount
    End With

ExitSub:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```